# main() sometimes keeps frame pointer with -fomit-frame-pointer on x86

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, x86-64

I accidentally discovered some strange thing about the -fomit-frame-pointer with GCC on x86 when I was doing homework.
Look at the following code (which seems quite nonsense but somehow related to how I discovered the problem)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void);

int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}

void foo()
{
    printf("0x%x\n", *(unsigned char *)main);
}
```

when compiled with `-m64 -O1` flag (-fomit-frame-pointer enabled), the disassembly is like the following

```
0000000000400500 <foo>:
  400500:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  400504:   0f b6 35 14 00 00 00    movzbl 0x14(%rip),%esi        # 40051f <main>
  40050b:   bf c4 05 40 00          mov    $0x4005c4,%edi
  400510:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400515:   e8 c6 fe ff ff          callq  4003e0 <printf@plt>
  40051a:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  40051e:   c3                      retq   

000000000040051f <main>:
  40051f:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  400523:   e8 d8 ff ff ff          callq  400500 <foo>
  400528:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  40052d:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  400531:   c3                      retq
```

Everything looks fine because %rbp does not show up at all. However when the code is compiled with `-m32 -O1` flag (starting from gcc 4.6 -fomit-frame-pointer becomes default and mine is GCC 4.8.2) or even use `-fomit-frame-pointer` explicitly, the disassembly is like the following.

```
08048400 <foo>:
 8048400:   83 ec 1c                sub    $0x1c,%esp
 8048403:   0f b6 05 1e 84 04 08    movzbl 0x804841e,%eax
 804840a:   89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
 804840e:   c7 04 24 c0 84 04 08    movl   $0x80484c0,(%esp)
 8048415:   e8 b6 fe ff ff          call   80482d0 <printf@plt>
 804841a:   83 c4 1c                add    $0x1c,%esp
 804841d:   c3                      ret    

0804841e <main>:
 804841e:   55                      push   %ebp
 804841f:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048421:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 8048424:   e8 d7 ff ff ff          call   8048400 <foo>
 8048429:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 804842e:   c9                      leave  
 804842f:   c3                      ret
```

The function `foo` looks quite the same in 32 bit and 64 bit. However, unlike the 64-bit one, the first two instructions of main are (notice that it is compiled with -fomit-frame-pointer):

```
push %ebp
mov %esp, %ebp
```

which resembles normal x86 code.
After several experiments I found that if `main` calls another function, the code will be like the one above, and if there is no function call in `main`, the code will resembles the 64-bit ones.

I know this question may seem strange but I'm just curious about why this difference exists between x86 and x86_64 code, and only exists with `main()` function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is unrelated to `-fomit-frame-pointer` as far as I know - instead it is a result of stack alignment.

`main` needs to align the stack (with `and $0xfffffff0, %esp`) so that the functions that it calls get the alignment they expect. This destroys the old value of `esp`, which consequently has to be saved and restored so that the `ret` does the right thing. (When the `ret` is executed, `esp` must be pointing at the same location it was upon entry to `main`: that is, at the return address that was saved on the stack).

So `esp` has to be saved and restored: and why not to a callee-save register such as `ebp`? In fact `ebp` is a good choice because there is a dedicated instruction, `leave`, to perform the desired `movl %ebp, %esp/popl %ebp` at the end of `main`.

On x64 the stack can be expected to be aligned upon entry to `main`, so alignment and the resulting saving and restoring of `esp` is unnecessary.

Comment: Does it do it specifically because it's `main`? I'd expect it when the `force_align_arg_pointer` attribute is used. Normally `main` isn't treated specially in any way.

Comment: Yes, it's specifically for `main`. By the way, `main` also gets minor special treatment from gcc in terms of error messages and, for C99, return value (defined to be 0 even if there is no `return` statement).